# Creating Multiple iPhone encrypted backups

Tags: itunes, ios, backup

Is it possible to create multiple encrypted backups with different passwords in different iTunes?

For example, if I create an encrypted backup in iTunes 1 with password 'abc' and then plug the device into into iTunes 2 on a different computer and try to create another encrypted backup. Will I be able to set password 'xyz'?

From then on, when I return to iTunes 1 will the backup password on that iTunes be 'abc' or 'xyz'?

Answer (score 2):

You can sync (and backup) your iDevice with *one* computer only, so the problem of assigning different passwords doesn't come up at all.